# how to transform data with 3 collection and $looup

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have three collection wanted to fetch records bases on their reference id, I got the result but wanted to transform the data how to make it.

```
 db.post.aggregate([
      {
        $lookup: {
          from: "users",
          localField: "created_by",
          foreignField: "_id",
          as: "users"
        }
      },
      {
        $lookup: {
          from: "comments",
          let: {
            p_id: "$_id"
          },
          pipeline: [
            {
              $match: {
                $expr: {
                  $eq: [
                    "$post_id",
                    "$$p_id"
                  ]
                }
              }
            }
          ],
          as: "comments"
        }
      },
      {
        $lookup: {
          from: "users",
          localField: "comments.sender_id",
          foreignField: "_id",
          as: "commented_user"
        }
      },

    ])
```

I am getting this result but what I want merge the commented_user into comments mean who has comments fetch the record.

```
[
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5eeb02881982961ada625c7d"),
    "commented_user": [
      {
        "_id": ObjectId("5e4d0973babf2b74ca868f4d"),
        "first_name": "James",
        "last_name": "Smith",
        "timestamp": 1.582106995137e+12
      }
    ],
    "comments": [
      {
        "_id": ObjectId("5eeb08e26fb7f270e4077617"),
        "date": 1.592461538923e+12,
        "post_id": ObjectId("5eeb02881982961ada625c7d"),
        "sender_id": ObjectId("5e4d0973babf2b74ca868f4d"),
        "text": "Nice One "
      }
    ],
    "created_by": ObjectId("5e4e74eb380054797d9db623"),
    "created_users": [],
    "date": 1.589441206774e+12,
    "title": "Covid19"
  }
]
```

Would better if I get each commented detail under comments like below ?

```
    "comments": [
          {
            "_id": ObjectId("5eeb08e26fb7f270e4077617"),
            "date": 1.592461538923e+12,
            "post_id": ObjectId("5eeb02881982961ada625c7d"),
            "sender_id": ObjectId("5e4d0973babf2b74ca868f4d"),
            "text": "Nice One ",
            "commented_user": [
            {
            "_id": ObjectId("5e4d0973babf2b74ca868f4d"),
            "first_name": "James",
            "last_name": "Smith",
            "timestamp": 1.582106995137e+12
          }
        ], 
          }
        ],
```

Here is mongoplayground https://mongoplayground.net/p/uw0kMTChFa0

Comment: Any help on this question ?

Answer (score 0):

You could use [$set](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/set/) and [$unset](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/unset/) or [$project](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) to format the outputs

[Example with unset](https://mongoplayground.net/p/EkLesPlzlLR) or [Example with project](https://mongoplayground.net/p/0pQEb3J-wvS)

**Updated [Example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/gLwY50QbpuB).** You need to [unwind](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) the `comments` array then perform [lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) for each comment to get the commented user.

```
db.post.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "users",
      localField: "created_by",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "created_users"
    }
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "comments",
      let: {
        p_id: "$_id"
      },
      pipeline: [
        {
          $match: {
            $expr: {
              $eq: [
                "$post_id",
                "$$p_id"
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      as: "comments"
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$comments"
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "users",
      localField: "comments.sender_id",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "commented_user"
    }
  },
  {
    $set: {
      "comments.commented_user": "$commented_user",
      
    }
  },
  {
    $unset: "commented_user"
  }
])
```

Comment: Thanks @nayakam but what I want to display only that commented user display who has commented https://mongoplayground.net/p/E_TIj8KlghY

Comment: expecting to display James smith not Alex because sender_id 5e4d0973babf2b74ca868f4d does match with James's id

Comment: or even if it is possible matching record display at first index ?

Comment: @SunilDubey Please check the updated example. Cheers